# The ideal background filesystem backup

Tags: windows, linux, backup, filesystems, background

I am thinking about a script/program that can run in background, and attempt to backup or synchronize a given filesystem path to a mirror location (probably located on an external/separate storage device).

This should apply to Windows but it could as well be used under Linux.

- Differential/incremental backups are a bonus.
- Windows System State backups are a bonus too.
- Keeping the origin free of meta-data is essential. (unlike version control)
- Searching by file or activity date could be interesting (like version control)
- Backup repositories should be easy to browse and take little space.
- Deleted files should be available for recovery for a period of time.
- Windows Backup is tedious and bloated and limited.
- Tar-gzipping is not accessible.
- User interaction during backup should be nonexistent.

Comment: Are you planning on programming this background filesystem backup?  Or are you looking for a pre-made solution?

Comment: Are you asking how to write such a backup system, or are you asking for recommendations of existing programs?

Comment: I fixed the formatting, but I'm not certain what the question is.

Comment: As much as the answers may be correct, this really isn't a programming question.

Comment: Thank you for editing Eddie.
I am asking about existing software that can be used by scripts, open systems that can provide an api/command system to be plugged into a custom app, or maybe even a full backup package.

I realise it's not a 100% programming question, thansk for bearing with me.

Comment: I didn't think the original question was quite explicit enough.  I understand now what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/) is free and creates encrypted, incremental, compressed offsite backups. It's a linux app, but you could run it in cygwin or a small virtual machine.

I've written a perl script that runs it via a cronjob to backup several very big directories over DSL and it works great.

Comment: A very good open source example, this looks like a very good fit to my requests, and it offers a good variety of storage protocols (scp/ssh, ftp, rsync, HSI, WebDAV and Amazon S3)

Answer (score 2):

[Amanda](http://www.amanda.org/) is the ultimate full-featured open-source backup solution, and there's a (relatively) new [Zmanda Windows Client](http://wiki.zmanda.com/index.php/Zmanda_Windows_Client).

Comment: Amanda appears to be more enterprise-oriented, both in usage as well as in features. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [AJCBackup](http://www.ajcsoft.com/index.php).  Does an excellent job at a good price.

Comment: The features are very close to my requirements, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

**Acronis True Image** is great. It's not free but the Home edition is pretty cheap for what it does and it works reliably. Does image- and file- based backups, scheduling, instant backup of chosen folders accessible from explorer context menu, incremental/differential backups, can mount the backup files as Windows volumes and browse them, copy files out etc. It has saved my ass a few times already.

Comment: I had no idea Acronis True Image can handle custom file backups, will definately look into